# How to fetch data from database and display it using AJAX in an app

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have not touched PHP or AJAX that much in about 8 years, so my memory on this is pretty low at the moment.

What I'm doing is fetching data from my database that works great.
Then I want to use AJAX to get the data from the PHP file.

My PHP file on my server is connecting to the database and fetching the table "Form".
This data is then going to be retrieved by another app trough AJAX.

I have a working PHP file, but how I should order this for the AJAX to fetch it nicely is a big question for me.

The things I have at the moment is:

PHP FILE:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}


$sql = "SELECT * FROM form";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $name       = $row['name'];
        $country    = $row['country'];
        $email      = $row['email'];
        $need       = $row['need'];
        $available  = $row['available'];

        echo "name: " . $name . "<br> Country: " . $country . " <br> Email: " . $email . "<br> Need: " . $need . "<br> Available: " . $available;

        $form_data = array();
        array_push($form_data)
    }
} else {
    echo "Null results";
}

$conn->close();


?>
```

AJAX FILE:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'url',
    data: "",

    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {

    }
});
```

The AJAX file is not complete since I'm still wondering about these PHP results.
Right now they are just stored in variables.
What is the best way to store these results to get an fetch for AJAX here?

Should I put the results in an array and then push that array into another array?
There can be many lines in forms, and I want 1 person with data: name, country etc to be in one array. Or is it stupid to have it in an array?

I hope someone can give a little clue and help me on my way here. Long time since I have been doing PHP and a little bit unclear about the best approach here.

Been searching for a while, but nothing made so much sense to me, so I'm coming here hoping someone can guide the way.

Happy Easter.

Comment: I would recommend returning the data from PHP as Json. Then you'll have a nice array with objects in your Ajax response.

Comment: Hei Magnus, and thank you for your answer.
Sorry for asking, but do you have an example of how to return the data as json?

should it be something like: echo json_encode($result);

Comment: Maybe not the `$result`-variable since that's a result-object. Create an array with the data in the way you want it and json encode that. You might also want to add a `header('Content-type: application/json');` before you echo the data.

Comment: Thanks again Magnus. Very good information.
I just gave it a go at the moment. Should it then be something like this?

`$form_data = array($name, $country, $email, $need, $available);
  $form_data = json_encode($form_data);

  header('Content-type: application/json');
  echo $form_data; `

Comment: Thanks again Magnus. It worked. Now I get all my results when I look in Raw Data. But i do get this error tho, and if I search for that error it says something about not calling json.parse, but I'm not.

SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 54 of the JSON data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an array and save all  your data, then `json_encode` to send the data to JavaScript.

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "db_julekgwa";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}


$sql = "SELECT * FROM form";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$rows = array();

if($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $name       = $row['name'];
        $country    = $row['country'];
        $email      = $row['email'];
        $need       = $row['need'];
        $available  = $row['available'];

        $rows[] = "{ name: " . $name . ", Country: " . $country . ", Email: " . $email . ", Need: " . $need . ", Available: " . $available . "}";

    }
    echo json_encode($rows);
} else {
    echo json_encode([ "error" => "Null results"]);
}

$conn->close();


?>
```

In your ajax do the following

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'file.php',
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      data.forEach(item => {
        console.log(item);
      });
    },
    error: function(data) {
      console.log(data);

    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you Junius L.
Just a quick question or two.

Why do $rows[] = "{Something}" instead of just $rows = array($name, $country) and so on. ?

And when I run this in the app, my console logs an object, and the array is stored in "responseText" as a string.

Can i take this responseText and make it into an array?

Comment: the response is an array, see my javascript code above.

Comment: this `$rows[]` adds the row to the array and after the while loop we push that data to javascript using `json_encode`

Comment: Okey. Thanks for that explanation @Junius L.
So to get something out of the objects responseText I have to call the responseText in the Object and get the array's in there?

Comment: where do you get `responseText `?

Comment: The Console.log(item) gives me an Object. This object contains alot of data.
One of them is responseText with a string with the data that the PHP file is fetching from the database.

Comment: did you use the example above?

Comment: Yes I did exactly as the example above.

Comment: The reason I get the responseText as I can see is that the error: is the one console logging and not the success. Seems like it can't get the data from the php file. @junius-l

Comment: Okey. I do get my data, but not as I want it.
In php I echo json_encode($form_data); and I do get my json result.

In ajax, when I run everything as above, I do get nothing. But when I run it but remove dataType: 'json' I do get my data as a String.
I have tried console.log(JSON.parse(data)); and that gives me an error of unexpected { at JSON.parse.

Comment: that might because you are echoing in the while loop.